# Method or data member not found vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have an userform designed with three listbox. The list box are populated from sheets, List_Dev_Red,List_Man_Red,List_SQM_Red. in my userform activate , I get an error "Method or data member" not found in the below line

> For xRow = 2 To Last(1, List_Dev_Red.Range("A:A"))

Could any one tel me what could be the reason for this error.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
Dim xRow As Integer
Dim yRow As Integer
Dim zrows As Integer

For xRow = 2 To Last(1, List_Dev_Red.Range("A:A"))
    With LB1
        .AddItem List_Dev_Red.Cells(xRow, 3).Value
        If List_Dev_Red.Cells(xRow, 2) = True Then
            .Selected(xRow - 2) = True
        Else
            .Selected(xRow - 2) = False
        End If
    End With
Next xRow
LB1.Height = (xRow - 1) * 15

For yRow = 2 To Last(1, List_Man_Red.Range("A:A"))
With LB2
.AddItem List_Man_Red.Cells(yRow, 3).Value
If List_Man_Red.Cells(yRow, 2) = True Then
.Selected(yRow - 2) = True
Else
.Selected(yRow - 2) = False
End If
End With
Next yRow
LB2.Height = (yRow - 1) * 15


For zrows = 2 To Last(1, List_SQM_Red.Range("A:A"))
With LB3
.AddItem List_SQM_Red.Cells(zrows, 3).Value
If List_SQM_Red.Cells(zrows, 2) = True Then
.Selected(zrows - 2) = True
Else
.Selected(zrows - 2) = False
End If
End With
Next zrows
LB3.Height = (zrows - 1) * 15
End Sub
```

Function Last ([from RondeBruin](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win005.htm)):

```
Function Last(choice As Long, rng As Range)
' 1 = last row
' 2 = last column
' 3 = last cell
    Dim lrw As Long
    Dim lcol As Long

    Select Case choice

    Case 1:
        On Error Resume Next
        Last = rng.Find(What:="*", _
                        After:=rng.Cells(1), _
                        LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                        MatchCase:=False).Row
        On Error GoTo 0

    Case 2:
        On Error Resume Next
        Last = rng.Find(What:="*", _
                        After:=rng.Cells(1), _
                        LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                        MatchCase:=False).Column
        On Error GoTo 0

    Case 3:
        On Error Resume Next
        lrw = rng.Find(What:="*", _
                       After:=rng.Cells(1), _
                       LookAt:=xlPart, _
                       LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                       SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                       SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                       MatchCase:=False).Row
        On Error GoTo 0

        On Error Resume Next
        lcol = rng.Find(What:="*", _
                        After:=rng.Cells(1), _
                        LookAt:=xlPart, _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                        MatchCase:=False).Column
        On Error GoTo 0

        On Error Resume Next
        Last = rng.Parent.Cells(lrw, lcol).Address(False, False)
        If Err.Number > 0 Then
            Last = rng.Cells(1).Address(False, False)
            Err.Clear
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0

    End Select


End Function
```

Comment: What is `Last(1, List_Dev_Red.Range("A:A"))` suppose to be ?

Comment: @ShaiRado last is the function, that check the rows and columns. and List_Dev_red is the sheet name

Comment: @Jenny - can you write the `Last()` function in the question?

Comment: Then you need to share the function as well, so we can see what happens there

Comment: @Vityata I have added the function to my code

Comment: @Jenny - can you add Public in front of Last? Like this -> `Public Function Last(choice As Long, rng As Range)`

Comment: @ShaiRado I have added#

Comment: @Vityata I still get the error

Comment: `Last` seems to return a cell address, not a row, which would be needed for the loop `Last = rng.Cells(1).Address(False, False)` you are doing `for x=1 to H255` for example   you need to return the `.row`

Comment: Write it like this: `For xRow = 2 To Last(1, List_Dev_Red.Range("A:A")).Row`

Comment: @Nathan_Sav I have six userforms, and all my six userforms almost follow the same. Just in this userform I am getting an error. Earlier I dint have, just now I started getting the error

Comment: @Vityata I still get the error with range

Comment: @ShaiRado why you deleted the post? I was trying to implement your solution

Comment: How is `List_Dev_Red` declared?

Comment: @Jenny - actually, if you are using code from somewhere (like the Last()) function, always make sure to mention it in the question - https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win005.htm Thus, you would save lot of time for debugging.

Comment: @Vityata ya, I am sorry for that. I will follow that here after

Comment: @Jenny - this kind of "rule" is only applicable, if you are using the code from a well-known site for VBA. Anyhow, cheers! :)

Comment: @Vityata I am sorry, It was not from any site. a colleague helped me with that code

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your syntax a bit (at the upper section of your code):

```
Dim xRow As Long
Dim yRow As Long
Dim zrows As Long
Dim LastRow As Long  ' <-- change all variables to Long (be on the safe side)

' get the last row by calling your Last function
LastRow = Last(1, List_Dev_Red.Range("A:A")) ' <-- you are passing a Range, and want to get a Long, representing the row number

' loop through your rows
For xRow = 2 To LastRow
    ' rest of your code

Next xRow
```

and make the change to your `Function` to return a `Long` (row number):

```
Function Last(choice As Long, rng As Range) As Long
```

Comment: Still I get the error. Also, I noticed that. after typing my sheet name. Range, I don't find range in the object listed.

Comment: @Jenny where do you have `List_Dev_Red` defined as `Worksheet` ? did you `Set` it ?

Comment: Do I need to define it as worksheet ? Because, I have already changed the sheet name to List_Dev_Red

Comment: @Jenny you need the following lines : `Dim List_Dev_Red As Worksheet` and `Set List_Dev_Red = Worksheets("YourSheetName")`

Comment: Now I get an error , object or with block variable not found

Comment: @Jenny, if you changed the name of that worksheet module to List_Dev_Red, then your syntax was fine.

Comment: Yeah, I have changed the name of my worksheet module

Comment: Or change the **codename** of the sheet in the VB Editor, rather than the tab caption.

Comment: If you had changed the code name of the sheet, you would see `Range` in the Intellisense.

Comment: codename = name of worksheet *module* imho. I think we're all talking about the same thing

Comment: @Rory I had the sheet name changed . and it was working fine. but now I could see that I don't have the sheet name assigned in the property. What could be the reason ?

Comment: @Rory in my case, this excel file is used by 3 other person in their machine

Comment: @ShaiRado - `Last` should be a Variant, returning either string or long. https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win005.htm

Comment: @Jenny If it was working, what is the problem? I don't see the relevance of the number of users.

Comment: @Rory it was working. but I don't know, it is not woking now

Answer (score 1):

In general, concerning that you know that you are looking for either column or row, you may use simplified functions like these:

```
Option Explicit

Function LastRow(sh As Worksheet) As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    LastRow = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                            After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                            Lookat:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Row
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Function LastCol(sh As Worksheet) As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    LastCol = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                            After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                            Lookat:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Column
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

They are from the same site [as the Variant function](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win005.htm).

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit
'***** VARIABLES *****
Public wbI As Workbook, wsChess As Worksheet
Public blackPlayer As cPlayer, whitePlayer As cPlayer
Public txtB_bPlayerName As TextBox, txtB_wPlayerName As TextBox

Public Sub initVars()

    Set wbI = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsChess = wbI.Sheets(1)

    'Works
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).txtB_bPlayerName.Value = ""

    'Don't work
    wsChess.txtB_wPlayerName.Value = ""

End Sub
```